# can't run a c++ file - Eclipse Yoxos

Tags: c++, eclipse

I downloaded Eclipse from Yoxos. This Eclispe includes: c, cpp, java etc..
However, when I opened a new cpp project with MinGW GCC Toolchains, and created a cpp file: hello.cpp, and wrote the following little program:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

when I run the file, it said - hello.exe has stopped working.

However, When I changed the program to: 
(first line in comment)

```
//#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("dsd");
    return 0;
}
```

It worked well!
and when I removed the first line from comment like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    printf("dsd");
    return 0;
}
```

the problem was back.. :(

Someone, Help..?
Thanks in advance! :)

Build Console Output:

```
20:41:10 **** Incremental Build of configuration Release for project hello ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o helo.o "..\\helo.cpp" 
g++ -o hello.exe helo.o 

20:41:11 Build Finished (took 610ms)
```

Comment: What's the actual compiler chosen to build? `gcc` or `g++`?

Comment: The actual compiler is g++

Comment: You may consider to add the actual build console's output to your question.

Comment: Done, I added it :)
Any ideas?